# determining function behavior from the type of the function

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell so sorry if this is very basic

This example is taken from "Real World Haskell" -

```
ghci> :type fst  
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

They show the type of the `fst` function and then follow it with this paragraph...

"The result type of `fst` is **`a`**. We've already mentioned that parametric polymorphism makes the real type inaccessible: `fst` doesn't have enough information to construct a value of type **`a`**, nor can it turn an **`a`** into a **`b`**. So the only possible valid behaviour (omitting infinite loops or crashes) it can have is to return the first element of the pair."

I feel like I am missing the fundamental point of the paragraph, and perhaps something important about Haskell.  Why couldn't the `fst` function return type **`b`**?  Why couldn't it take the tuple as a param, but simply return an `Int` ( or any other type that is NOT **`a`**)?  I don't understand why it MUST return type **`a`**?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it did any of those things, its type would change. What the quote is saying is that, given that we know `fst` is of type `(a, b) -> a`, we can make those deductions about it. If it had a different type, we would not be able to do so.

For instance, see that

```
snd :: (a, b) -> a
snd (x, y) = y
```

does not type-check, and so we know a value of type `(a, b) -> a` cannot behave like `snd`.

Parametricity is basically the fact that a polymorphic function of a certain type must obey certain laws *by construction* — i.e., there is no well-typed expression of that type that does not obey them. So, for it to be possible to prove things about `fst` with it, we must first know `fst`'s type.

Note especially the word *polymorphism* there: we can't do the same kind of deductions about non-polymorphic types. For instance,

```
myFst :: (Int, String) -> Int
myFst (a, b) = a
```

type-checks, but so does

```
myFst :: (Int, String) -> Int
myFst (a, b) = 42
```

and even

```
myFst :: (Int, String) -> Int
myFst (a, b) = length b
```

Parametricity relies crucially on the fact that a polymorphic function can't "look" at the types it is called with. So the only value of type *a* that `fst` knows about is the one it's given: the first element of the tuple.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that once you have that type, the implementation options are greatly limited. If you returned an `Int`, then your type would be `(a,b) -> Int`. Since `a` could be anything, we can't gin one up out of thin air in the implementation without resorting to `undefined`, and so must return the one given to us by the caller.

Answer (score 4):

You should read the [Theorems for Free](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.9875) article.

Comment: Before finishing chapter 2 of RWH?

Comment: @ehird he wanted an in-depth explanation, so here it is. Basic hand-waving explanation have already been given by other people

Comment: Fair enough. I tried to avoid hand-waving in my answer, though, but I'm certainly not perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to add some more hand-waving to that already given by Real World Haskell. Lets try to convince ourselves that given that we have a function `fst` with type `(a,b) -> a` the only  total function it can be is the following one:

```
fst (x,y) = x
```

First of all, we cannot return anything other then a value of type `a`, that is in the premise that fst has type `(a,b) -> a`, so we cannot have `fst (x,y) = y` or `fst (x,y) = 1` because that does not have the correct type.

Now, as RWH says, if I give `fst` an `(Int,Int)`, `fst` doesn't know these are Ints, furthermore, `a` or `b` are not required to belong to any type class so `fst` has no available values or functions associated with `a` or `b`.

So `fst` only knows about the `a` value and the `b` value that I give it and I can't turn `b` into an `a` (It can't make a `b -> a` function) so it must return the given `a` value.

This isn't actually just magical hand waving, one can actually deduce what possible expressions there are of a given polymorphic type. There is actually a program called [djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn) that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that both `a` and `b` are type variables (that might be the same, but that's not needed). Anyway, since for a given tuple of two elements, `fst` returns always the first element, the returned type must be always the same as the type for the first element.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental thing you're probably missing is this:

- In most programming languages, if you say "this function returns any type", it means that *the function* can decide what type of value it actually returns.
- In Haskell, if you say "this function returns any type", it means that *the caller* gets to decide what type that should be. (!)

So if I you write `foo :: Int -> x`, it can't just return a `String`, because I might not ask it for a `String`. I might ask for a `Customer`, or a `ThreadId`, or *anything*.

Obviously, there's no way that `foo` can know how to create a value of every possible type, even types that don't exist yet. In short, it is impossible to write `foo`. Everything you try will give you type errors, and won't compile.

(Caveat: There is *a* way to do it. `foo` could loop forever, or throw an exception. But it *cannot* return a valid value.)

There's no way for a function to be able to create values of any possible type. But it's *perfectly possible* for a function to move data around without caring what type it is. Therefore, if you see a function that accepts any kind of data, the only thing it can be doing with it is to move it around.

Alternatively, if the type has to belong to a specific class, then the function can use the methods of that class on it. (*Could*. It doesn't have to, but it *can* if it wants to.)

Fundamentally, this is why you can actually tell *what a function does* just by looking at its *type signature*. The type signature tells you what the function "knows" about the data it's going to be given, and hence what possible operations it might perform. This is why searching for a Haskell function by its type signature is so damned useful.

You've heard the expression "in Haskell, if it compiles, it usually works right"? Well, this is why. ;-)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of the ideas behind parametricity! Now we just need a similarly understandable translation of Wadler's proofs in "Theorems for Free".

Comment: @dfeuer If you find one, let me know! I keep seeing that phrase, but have no clue what it means...