# Is it possible to force a type to a class in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell

As an example, say I wish to implement a function which sums up a list of `Num`s. Halfway through coding it, I wish to debug it with `Debug.Trace`:

```
module T where
import Debug.Trace

dosum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
dosum xs = dosum' 0 xs
    where
        dosum' n [] = n
        dosum' n (x:xs) = trace (show n) $ dosum' (n+x) xs
```

The problem is that this will not compile:

```
Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of dosum'
from the context (Num a)
```

I can add `(Show a)` to `dosum` and then remove it when I am finished debugging (in real life, I will want to have a type which is not necessarily in `Show`, but I will debug with integers). This can get cumbersome if there are a few functions involved and I keep adding removing `Show a` statements.

I want to have a function `unsafeShow`

```
unsafeShow :: a -> String
```

which works if `a` is `Show a` and is free to crash if it is not. Is this possible?

Comment: You could comment out the signature while debugging.

Comment: @DanielFischer: problem is if dosum is at the bottom of a stack, I end up commenting/uncommenting multiple functions all the time and it's very annoying.

Comment: Perhaps(?) lesser evil: `#ifdef DEBUG`

Comment: This does compile, `Num` is a subclass of `Show` ;) But in general case I guess it can't be done. Not for ghc or other "usual" implementations. A "usual" implementation does not have values type-tagged, and so cannot discover at runtime any type information it doesn't know at compile time.

Comment: @n.m.: `Num` isn't a subclass of `Show` any more. The `(Eq a, Show a)` context was removed in the February release of base 4.5.0.0, which shipped with GHC 7.4.1.

Comment: @ehird: Thanks. I only have 7.2 on this machine...

Comment: If you are dealing with `Num`bers, it is highly likely that they are also an instance of `Show`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The really really terrible answer is to use `unsafeCoerce` from the `Unsafe.Coerce` module. It is as it sounds – it is a general tool for bypassing the type system, and if you get it wrong, you won't get a type error or an exception, you will get a segmentation fault.

In this case, you can `unsafeCoerce` a value that you already know is an `Integer` to `Integer` so that the type system can recognise that it's an integer too. Then you can show it as usual (make sure to give an explicit type signature, so `show` knows what it is showing – it can't infer, since `unsafeCoerce` can return any type!)

But if you accidentally call the code with `unsafeCoerce` on something other than an `Integer`, crashes, memory corruption, anything could happen – you've just completely thrown away your safety net.

In general, the only "safe" uses of `unsafeCoerce` are between types that *you* already know are equal, but the typechecker doesn't (or some other specialised use-cases, see [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Unsafe-Coerce.html)). Even then it will be heavily frowned upon by anyone reading your code unless your comments explain why it is the only option.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually pretty close to what I wanted. I did not know about ``unsafeCoerce``

Comment: I accepted this as I wrote ``showInt ai = show (unsafeCoerce ai :: Int)`` which has type ``showInt :: a -> String`` and does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm not even convinced there's any way to make this work that gets you anywhere that the normal `show` didn't get you.

Answer (score 13):

No, this is not possible. It would violate [parametricity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524801/determining-function-behavior-from-the-type-of-the-function); a polymorphic function is not allowed to behave differently based on the specific type it is called with. It would also break the open world assumption, in that adding a `Show` instance for a type would change the behaviour of your program.

It could be a useful debugging aid, as something explicitly marked unsafe, but GHC does not support such a function, and I don't think its current implementation would permit the easy addition of one.

A possible alternative, if you have many functions with the same typeclass context that you want to do this with, and there is a conceptual semantic grouping to, would be to have a class like

```
class (Num a) => Number a
instance (Num a) => Number a
```

which you can use instead of `Num` in signatures, changing the declaration to `(Num a, Show a)` when debugging. (It would be better to pick a more meaningful name than `Number`, however!)

Comment: Thanks. I agree that this is an awful idea in general. I just want it for debug.

Comment: In GHC 7.4.1 with `ConstraintKinds` you can also just write `type Number a = Num a` or `type Number a = (Show a, Num a)` and then write functions `f :: (Number a) => a -> a -> a`

Comment: Nice explanation. I kinda sorta knew it was not possible, but this sentence cleared it up for me: "adding a Show instance for a type would change the behaviour of your program."

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. (note [1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vacuum/1.0.0.2/doc/html/GHC-Vacuum.html#v%3avacuum))

---

[1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vacuum/1.0.0.2/doc/html/GHC-Vacuum.html#v%3avacuum): An exception is that you can dump the heap structure of GHC's heap, via an `a -> String` function. You can e.g. always turn a value into a hexadecimal pointer value, via [vacuum](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vacuum/1.0.0.2/doc/html/GHC-Vacuum.html#v%3avacuum). This is unlikely to be what you want. This functionality is the same as that used by the GHCi debugger to show arbitrary heap values.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to implement your `unsafeShow` function in pure Haskell. The GHC could provide one, but currently it doesn't.

You might check out the GHCi debugger, however. This allows you to print stuff out that doesn't have a `Show` instance. (Further, it allows you to avoid evaluating something that wouldn't otherwise be evaluated, which can be useful.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would comment out the type signature, but if a function is deep in the tree that gets annoying.  You can try using rewrite rules to replace your polymorphic function with the modified variant.

```
-- original function, should add NOINLINE to make sure your rule gets a chance to fire.
{-# NOINLINE dosum #-}
dosum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a

-- a version with added debugging
dosumShow :: (Num a, Show a) => [a] -> a

{-# RULES "sub/dosum" forall x. dosum x = dosumShow x #-}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's GHC version 7.4.1? From it [release notes](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html):

> The Num class no longer has Eq or Show superclasses. A number of other classes and functions have therefore gained explicit Eq or Show constraints, rather than relying on a Num constraint to provide them.
>
> You can make code that works with both Haskell98/Haskell2010 and GHC by:
>
> - Whenever you make a Num instance of a type, also make Show and Eq instances, and
> - Whenever you give a function, instance or class a Num t constraint, also give it Show t and Eq t constraints.

Your code works well in previous versions of GHC (I try in 7.0.4).

Comment: Yes, it's modern GHC. The ``Num`` was an example which happened to work well on modern GHC, but I wanted to have the more general question (my actual example is with ByteStrings, but I thought integers would make a simpler example).

Comment: Ok, I see, if `foo` has `Show` in its context and `bar` calls `foo` then `bar` must has `Show` in its context, and so on. Maybe you need to reimplement old `Num` like this `class (Show t, Eq t, Num t) => NumDebug t` and then switch between `Num` and `NumDebug`? If you has `trace (show n) ...` when `n` is non-ad-hoc polymorphic (say, `Integer`) then there is no problems.