# Haskell "man" Pages?

Tags: haskell, manpage

Are there man pages for each individual function in Haskell? In other words can I type `man fst` somewhere and get a man or help page about the function? I am finding the profusion of functions overwhelming!

I am using GHC and GHCi.

Comment: Sounds like a fun idea to implement (as a backend for haddock).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of a command-line tool for this, but you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find the type of a function, a quick summary of its documentation, and a link to the full online documentation based on its name.

It even works the other way: going from a type to functions that match that type! This is extremely useful if you think a function must exist for a certain purpose, but don't know what it's called or where it is.

There's also [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html), which searches the entirety of [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) (whereas Hoogle only searches standard libraries), but it's probably less useful for this specific purpose: a search for "fst" returns the obsolete `haskell98` package first, and the relevant `base` package third.

From within GHCi, you can often get some information about what a function does simply by checking its type; for instance, if you do

```
GHCi> :t fst
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

then you know that `fst` must return the first element of the tuple you give it, because [that's all a function of that type *can* do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524801/determining-function-behavior-from-the-type-of-the-function).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Yep, but as far as I know, the command-line tool doesn't include or link to the documentation.

Comment: I believe Leksah also has some sort of (hoogle-based?) documentation browser.

Comment: @DanBurton same for EclipseFP.

Answer (score 4):

I found it useful to [integrate Hoogle into GHCi](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hoogle#GHCi_Integration):

```
$ cabal install hoogle
$ echo >> ~/.ghci ':def doc \x -> return $ ":!hoogle --info \"" ++ x ++ "\""'

Download and build Hoogle databases:
$ hoogle data
```

Then you can do this inside GHCi:

```
ghci> :doc fst
Prelude fst :: (a, b) -> a

Extract the first component of a pair. 

From package base
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

Comment: My only gripe about this is that it doesn't properly escape `"` in `x`. I would think it better to invoke `hoogle` in a more typical Haskell fashion rather than using GHCi's `:!`.